# Good introduction to infinite dimensional linear systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, infinite-matrices

I'm searching for some introductory material to infinite-dimensional linear systems, but on the web I'm running into mainly control theory references and things about applied mathematics and/or physics. Is there some good reference that treats the topic at an elementary level? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you mean without operator theory ?

Comment: @JeanMarie no no with operator theory is all good! I think I learn best with a theoretical introduction first and seeing the applications later on. So if operator theory is involved (bounded linear operators I guess?) it would be perfect